# php intermittent parse syntax error

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error

I am experiencing an intermittent parse/syntax error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /folder/folder/path.php on line 3
```

Here is the php:

```
//define include path
$path =    array('/classes','/css','/css/images','/dompdf','/html','/img','/js','/methods',    '/php','/php/functions');
(>this is line 3... a BLANK line)
foreach ($path as $value):
set_include_path(get_include_path() . ":" .$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $value);
   endforeach;
```

The file is called by index.php which states at line 7

```
require_once "/folder/folder/path.php";
```

Sometimes i get this error, sometimes i don't - i can't find or figure out any pattern for the error occurring! I'd really appreciate if you could throw some light on this.

Comment: what is your line number 2? show more codes to find the error cause.

Comment: Hi Naga - that is the whole file. (<this is line 3... a BLANK line) is written on line 3, and line 2 immediately above it is line beginning '$path = array('...

Comment: If that's the whole file, then you're missing an opening `<?php`

Comment: My mistake MArk - you are quite right. I missed the opening "<?php" for this post. Plesae assume "<?php" on line 1, and add 1 digit to each subsequent line number.

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of 'noob' errors.
Firstly i forgot to turn on
    error_reporting(E_ALL)

and 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1)

What i discovered were two issues. The error was actually being generated from an included file. I needed to be in the session (duh!)!!!

Secondly, on the odd occasion i was trying to include the file that defines the path inside a CLASS DEFINITION.

HOWEVER, because the class definition file is an included file, it is included in the session of the calling file and there is no need to define the path.

I am still not sure where the erroneous "{" came from - i am guessing it was actually referring to the ":" at the end of the foreach statement inside the path.php file?

Anyway, hope this helps someone else too.